# How to change background color of divs on mouse click and drag with the HTML5 color input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the background color of my divs by clicking and dragging over them to the value of the color from the color input.
HTML:

```
<div class="center">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>

<div class="center" id="colorDiv">
  <input type="color" id="colorPicker">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var div = $('.square');
div.mousedown(function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", $("#colorPicker").val());
});
```

Here is my [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/57u7Lda3/3/)
This is the effect I want but with the color value: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7Wkm2/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Do this with your jQuery:

```
    var div = $('.square');
    div.mousedown(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", $("#colorPicker").val());
        //add this line
        div.on("mouseenter.square",function(){
             $(this).css("background-color", $("#colorPicker").val());
        });
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, what this is also doing is after I click one square then just moving the mouse across the other squares are also changing their colors. I only want the color to change if the mouse is down and moving across them.

Comment: @IshT., then you need to change back the color to what it was before `onmouseup`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').on('change', function() {
        var color = $("#colorPicker").val();
        $(".square").css("background-color", color);
    });
});
</script>
<div class="center">
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
</div>

<div class="center" id="colorDiv">
<input type="color" id="colorPicker">
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.square
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}
#colorPicker
{
    top: 20%;
    position: relative;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want.

```
var div = $('.square')
div.mousedown(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", $("#colorPicker").val())
    div.mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", $("#colorPicker").val())
    })
})
$(document).mouseup(function() {
    div.off('mouseenter')
})
```

Comment: This is very much exactly what I wanted, thank you very much for the help!